# Existe equivalente ao Call do VB.NET no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

A pergunta é simples. Existe uma palavra-chave equivalente ao `Call` do Visual Basic.NET em C#?

Em Visual Basic, chamava um método de uma classe sem precisar declarar um membro explicitamente para ela:

```
Call New Form() With {.Text = "Olá, mundo!"}.ShowDialog()
```

Isso tudo acima seria o equivalente à isso em C#:

```
Form tmp = new Form() { Text = "Olá, mundo!" };
tmp.ShowDialog();
tmp.Dispose();
```

Eu acho muito útil essa palavra-chave pelo fato dela economizar espaço em código, organização e gerenciamento de memória, pois descarta os objetos usados após o fim da utilização.

Existe alguma maneira de chamar um membro, *lambda*, ou procedimento que o `Call` faz, mas em C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O equivalente em C# seria:

```
(new Form() { Text = "Olá, mundo!" }).ShowDialog();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/OneLinerHelloWorld.cs).

Pode estar se perguntando onde está a 3a. linha. Deveria existir na versão em VB.NET também, já que optou por não ter não tem porque adicionar em C#.

Na verdade esse código não faz muito sentido assim.

A economia aparente do VB.NET é só porque ele faz bem menos que a versão do C#, mesmo na atribuição de variável que é uma operação a mais que o código está fazendo. Não é o `Call` que está ajudando, é o fato do código fazer menos. Na verdade comparando com o C#, como quase tudo em VB.NET, o código fica mais verboso se fizer a mesma coisa.